# Токен авторизации Office365

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-websites, office365

Известно, что приложения из пакета office365 обмениваются между собой токеном авторизации, который очевидно как-то формируется на основе аккаунтов пользователей в Azure Active Directory. Если в Azure завести новое приложение и выбрать в нем тип авторизации через облако, то по идее все должно работать по такой же схеме.
На деле, если зайти в какое-нибудь приложение office365, а потом из него перейти в моё приложение, то токен в него передается. А если попробовать войти в моё приложение напрямую, то токен тоже вроде формируется, но с ошибками. По какому принципу вообще работает авторизация в office365? Реально ли сделать такую же в своем приложении?

Comment: В Office365 токен может генерироваться либо Azure AD либо твоим ADFS-Сервером. Как происходит авторизация пользователей? Через ADFS или это просто Cloud Users?

Comment: @WalterNuss через АДФС

Comment: Тогда токен генерирует ADFS

Comment: @WalterNuss выходит, в моем приложении нужно тоже сделать авторизацию через адфс? и тогда токены будут идентичными?

Comment: А почему токены должны быть идеентичными? Как поставлена бизнесс-задача?

Comment: @WalterNuss Когда пользователь у нас заходит в офис365, токен всегда правильный и безошибочный, а когда заходит в моё приложение, то токен у одних валидный, а у других нет. Хочется понять, как сделать так, чтобы токен формировался точно так же, как у офиса

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39057/discussion-between-walter-nuss-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как авторизация происходит через ADFS-Сервер, то необходимо имплементировать в приложении авторизацию через этот сервер. ADFS сервер генерирует токен (куки), который сохраняется в браузере. Затем при попытке доступа к Office365 или твоему приложению проверяется наличие и валидность этого куки.

В ADFS сервере надо будет настроить новый Claim, а затем привязать аутентификацию через этот клэйм в приложении. [Вот оффициальный туториал на эту тему.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545401%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Вот ещё [полезный туториал.](http://gavindraper.com/2013/01/31/ad-fs-token-based-authentication-in-code/)